# How do I make only the character strings lowercase for every data object in the environment? OR every element in a list

Tags: r, class, dplyr, lowercase

I have a large number of data frame objects, and I want to apply a function that only converts the character strings to lowercase and leaves the classes of every thing else alone.

I have tried `mutate_all(df,tolower)` but that affected all variables/columns

I have tried `mutate_at(names(select_if(df,is.character)),tolower)` and this does work on an individual dataframe. But I need to do this across many data frames all at the same time. I am really bad at Iteration and loops, so if code that iterates this line of code over every object may be a solution.

Or, because I also have these dataframes in a list, I have tried

`modify_depth(df,.depth = 2, mutate_at(names(select_if(,is.character)),tolower))`
But that did not work. `modify` is in the purrr package

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data_frame_Rate_Table <- data.frame(Policy_Class = c("rED", "WhIte","BlUe"),
                                   Rate=c(3,9,19),"Factor_1"= 1:3, Factor_2=7:9, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_frame_Policyholders <- data.frame(Policy_number  = 1:10,
                                       Policy_Class=rep(c("REd","red","wHite","BLue","bluE"),2),
                                       Risk=c(rep("HiGh",5),rep("LOW",5)), 
                                       Lapse=rep(c("Y","N"),5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_frame_list <- list(data_frame_Policyholders, data_frame_Rate_Table)
```

I would just like all character strings to be lowercase without affecting the other classes.

Comment: and over a list of dataframes `map(data_frame_list, ~mutate_if(.x,is.character,tolower))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"and over a list of `dataframes map(data_frame_list, ~mutate_if(.x,is.character,tolower))` "– AndS. 7 mins ago

This was a comment from AndS and it is EXACTLY what I wanted to happen. Thank you AndS!

I made this an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `rapply` in base R.

```
data_frame_list <- rapply(data_frame_list, function(x) 
  if(is.character(x)) tolower(x) else x, how="replace")
# [[1]]
#    Policy_number Policy_Class Risk Lapse
# 1              1          red high     y
# 2              2          red high     n
# 3              3        white high     y
# 4              4         blue high     n
# 5              5         blue high     y
# 6              6          red  low     n
# 7              7          red  low     y
# 8              8        white  low     n
# 9              9         blue  low     y
# 10            10         blue  low     n
# 
# [[2]]
#   Policy_Class Rate Factor_1 Factor_2
# 1          red    3        1        7
# 2        white    9        2        8
# 3         blue   19        3        9
```